# Accessing Openshift Secrets Data in Python Script

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables, openshift

I have a script that is accessing my environment variables using `os.environ.get('env_var_name')`. I can run this locally, but in Openshift I have my Secrets stored where a single Secret contains multiple Data values. For instance a `Test1` Secret would have `env_var_1`, `env_var_2`, etc. stored as Data in the Secret.

My question is, how do I access each variable individually inside my python script? I've attempted something like `os.environ.get(Test1/env_var_1)` and `os.environ.get(Test1.env_var_1)`, but neither have worked so far. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you rightly siad, you can't access them using `os.environ.get()` because that method retrieves environment variables from the underlying operating system. That's why it worked in your dev environment. However it does not from OpenShift Secrets. In openShift, you need to use the OpenShift API or cli tools. In your Python script, you can use the subprocess module to run shell commands and capture the output.

Something along these lines should work for you

```
secret_name = "Test1"
env_var_name = "env_var_1"

command = f'oc get secret {secret_name} -o jsonpath={{.data.{env_var_name}}} | base64 -d'
result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, check=True, text=True, capture_output=True)

value = result.stdout.strip()
print(f"The value of {env_var_name} is: {value}")
```

Remember to import subprocess module if you've not done so already.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes / OpenShift, just mount your Secret as an environmrnt variable by defining this in the container:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: envfrom-secret
spec:
  containers:
  - name: envars-test-container
    image: myimage
    envFrom:
    - secretRef:
        name: test1
```

Now you can just continue to use ‚env_var_1‘ and similar in Python as you would locally. The value will always be populated from the Secret.